# How to delete a scheduled sidekiq job, running every minutes even if all code related to this job disappeared from the code base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activejob, sidekiq-cron

I guess everything is in the title. I scheduled a job on scheduler.rb weeks ago. It was suppose to run every minutes. We are not using it anymore.

I'm trying to delete it for good but it's still running on sidekiq and appears as failed since there is no code related to this job anymore in my code base.

[here is what i see in sidekiq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYZfI.png)

Any idea here ?

Comment: what gem are you using (other than sidekiq)?
sidekiq-cron ? whenever ? rufus ?

Comment: Afaik you can just mark the job on the Sidekiq web UI and delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the box, click the "Kill" button.